# Asp.net Identity Role in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this working RoleController and its View which list all the roles

RoleController class:

```
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public RoleController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
        return View(roles);
    }  
}
```

Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>List of Roles</h1>
<a asp-action="Create">Create</a>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var role in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@role.Id</td>
                <td>@role.Name</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@role.Id" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I would like to migrate these code to Razor Pages. And this is what I have created:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public IndexModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var roles = await roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();

        return Page();
    }
}
```

In MVC version, it returns `roles` to the View. But for Razor Pages version, what should it returns since it has model binding feature?

Comment: Roles and views don't exist in Razor Pages. You're thinking of MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>List of Roles</h1>
<a asp-action="Create">Create</a>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var role in Model.roles)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@role.Id</td>
                <td>@role.Name</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@role.Id" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public IndexModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }
    public List <IdentityRole> roles { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        roles = await roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
        
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
namespace IdentityRazor3_1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IdentityRazor3_1.Pages.IndexModel
```

If you do not want to specify the same namespace every time,you could add the following code to your `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using IdentityRazor3_1.Pages
```

Or:

```
@namespace IdentityRazor3_1.Pages
```

Comment: I tried your code. Just that there is a syntax error at `@model IndexModel` which says `The type or namespace name 'IndexModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Check your IndexModel's namespace.And add reference to it.And be sure you have created the correct razor pages project.Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).Check my updated answer.